# Django admin list filter date each month

Tags: python, django

ModelAdmin:

```
class PedidoComissaoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['artista', 'pedido', 'pedido_data',
                    'pedidoitem', 'valor_receber', 'data_pagamento',
                    'status', 'origem_venda']
    list_filter = ['artista__nome', 'pedido__data']
    actions = ['status_pago']
```

Model:

```
class PedidoComissao(models.Model):
    artista = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name='Artista')
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido)
    pedidoitem = models.ForeignKey(PedidoItem, verbose_name='Arte')
    valor_receber = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    data_pagamento = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    origem_venda = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
```

By this way it filters:

- Today
- Last 7 days
- This month
- This Year

How I filter the date each month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [django-daterange-filter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-daterange-filter) package.